# rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link VS. Coding implementation

Tags: navigation, mapping, amcl-pose, base-link, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to calculate robot's current position with respect to the map.
**Following is my "rosrun tf view_frames"**

[tf tree](http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/13988714412451395.jpg)

I have tried following commands which gives robot position with respect to /map frame.

**rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link**

***Output*** is here:[map to base_link.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1399291760642935.jpg)

**Now same thing, I tried to  perform using the code**  [here](http://pastebin.com/Z5pVWaTn)

But the output of rxconsole is shown below::
[transform.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13992918927182973.jpg).

**I am just wondering why the results of the code and that of "rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link" is not matching?**

I **am getting "Got a transform! x = 0.000000, y =0.000000",** even after 1sec when I use the code. **But "rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link", gives actual robot position** with respect to the map as you can see the **screen shot**.

**Question1:** Is there any way to get the exact position of the robot while moving in the environment?

**Question 2**:  I don’t know how the above command gives position of the robot with respect to the map, but the implementation of the SAME COMMAND gives some INVALID result?

**Question 3:**  Is there any way to **emulate the command "rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link" in coding**?

Please help..........

Many Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161326/rosrun-tf-tf_echo-/map-/base_link-vs.-coding-implementation./) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nursima](https://answers.ros.org/users/50890/nursima/) on 2020-01-14**:
Hi, is it possible that you share the code via another method? I have no access to pastebin.com and I didn't manage to overcome it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer, forgot to add

> listener.lookupTransform("/map","/base_link",ros::Time(0),
> transform);

---

Originally posted by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) with karma: 229 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2